# Coded UI Tests on Azure with On-Prem Test controller

Tags: azure, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests, azure-virtual-network

I have a domain-joined machine which I would be using as a test controller. I want to use Azure VMs as test agents. For that, I have created a virtual network and installed point-to-site connectivity along with the VPN client on my machine. I want to register the test agent with the controller on my machine. But the test agent configuration tool doesn't accept the domain credentials. Is there a way to establish bi-directional communication between test agent and the controller in such a situation?

EDIT: This is the log error

Got Exception :

> Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.ConfigCore.ConfigToolException:
>   Failed to register this test agent with the test controller. Possible
>   reasons could be you do not have permissions to connect to the test
>   controller or a firewall is blocking the connection. To fix this
>   problem, verify the test controller is running and you have
>   appropriate permissions to register test agent with the test
>   controller. Refer to this page for more details:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=212977&clcid=0x409 --->  I,
>   2015/04/22, 11:38:00.904, CreateControllerObject: attempt 0,
>   System.Security.Authentication.InvalidCredentialException: The server
>   has rejected the client credentials. --->
>   System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The logon attempt failed    ---
>   End of inner exception stack trace ---

Comment: I thought they already did on ports 6910 and 6901?

Comment: I added the error I get in the test agent logs.

Comment: Are the controller and agent listening on the correct ports : netstat -a

Comment: Is the port blocked for that user?, are you using the same user for both accounts such as domain\user? 
telnet domain.com 6901
telnet domain.com 6910

Comment: The controller is listening on the port 6901 however I don't see the agent listening on either 6910 or 6901. I've created a local account on both machines with same credentials and as administrators.

Comment: and the telnet from the agent to the controller worked?

Comment: What do you mean by 'doesn't accept the domain credentials' ? That user does not have admin access on the agent? They are on a different domain? Can you run any other program with those credentials? Can you run a telnet with those credentials?